# Alert box disappears on page refresh while validation is in progress

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" id="MyForm" name="MyForm">
<table id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="Fie">
                A</label>
            <input id="A" name="A" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="B">
                B</label>
            <input id="B" name="B" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="submitButton" class="k-button">Next</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').click(function () {
        $('#MyForm').submit();
        if ($('#MyForm').valid()) {
            alert('hi')
        }
        return false;
    });
    $('#MyForm').validate(
    {
        rules: {
            A:
            {
                required: false,
                range: [1, 100]
            },
            B: {
                required: false,
                range: [1, 100]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            A: {
                range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid range")
            },
            B: {
                range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid range")
            }
        }
        ,
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.invoicePrintForm').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        }
    });
});
```

### **[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rg5/)**

**Question**

When I click the button, including all values are valid. It is suppose to show the alert message. Alert Message comes but disappears while refresh. Please check the JSFiddle.

Comment: try removing $('#MyForm').submit();

Comment: @iBlue : Can you show JSFiddle ?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/a4rg5/3/

Comment: Try without values in textbox it is still showing Alert message in fiddle.

Comment: @iBlue : Can you add it as answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the validation isn't working.Try removing

```
$('#MyForm').submit();
```

It will fix the refresh after alert

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4rg5/3/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submitButton').click(function () {

            if ($('#MyForm').valid()) {
               alert('valid');
            }
            return false;
        });
       });
```